# Plotting zedgraph curve with x, y as pair of arrays

Tags: c#, plot, zedgraph

I have two arrays dates and values

```
DateTime[] dates = new DateTime[96];
decimal[] values = new decimal[96];
```

I want to plot a curve using zedgraph with dates as my x-axis and values as my y-axis. I have tried using many `zedgraph` examples but I didn't succeed.

Comment: Which examples did you try exactly?

Comment: i have tried winforms using  zedgraph here is my example:sample code

Comment: myPane.XAxis.Scale.Format = "HH:mm:ss\nyy/MM/dd";
PointPairList list = new PointPairList();       
DateTime [] sDates = { 2013-07-27, 2013-07-28, 2013-07-29, 2013-07-30, 2013) double[] sVal1 = { 2.3, 3.5, 7.0, 9.3,5.7);               for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
     {
                PointPairList ppl = new PointPairList();
               for (int p = 0; p < 5; p++){
               PointPairList ppl = new PointPairList();
               double x =(double) new XDate(DateTime.Now)}list.Add(x, y);